# Which is correct? I go to school by bus or I go by bus to school

Tags: tenses

Which is correct?

> I go to school by bus every day

or

> I go by bus to school every day.

What about SVOMPT? I would say the first sentence.

Comment: Both are fine...the prepositions keep clarity.

Comment: I'd say the first is the unmarked version. Splitting the set phrase 'go to school', which some would argue is more cohesive than V + PP, jars.

Comment: The first doesn't and there might not be anything specifically wrong with it but still "I go by bus to school every day" does raise queries. Personally I don't see any problem with the first, and I think the second depends entirely on context…

Comment: ... which is pretty much what I said, and you question it ~.~

Comment: The first is probably more idiomatic in the US, but they're both perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Both mean the same thing, just written differently. It's truly optional and based on your style of writing.

Answer (score -2):

The first form is a statement that you go to school using the bus, every day (presumably every day that you go to school, not literally every day).

The second form is the answer to the question *How do you go to school? Do you always go the same way?*

Comment: I don't think that's half as clear as you do, Will. Could you explain how Example 2 is in any way justified, please? Ex 1 clearly serves but to me, Ex 2 raises more questions than it answers…

Comment: True, but that sense of confusion IS what I wanted to highlight. I'd render it differently, but ultimately it reads like it's an "alternative" word order intended to emphasise something - *it is **by bus** that I go to school, every day!* vs *I go to school every day. I use the bus.*

Comment: Uh… thanks and that's to move the goal posts. Would you rather deal with what you originally posted, or this different variation, or their combination?

Comment: No, I've given further explanation of why I don't like the second form. It, as you said yourself *raises further queries*. It doesn't look like the right wording for a simple statement. That's my point, entirely.